CAS 6.6.15 created service ticket results in INVALID_SERVICE
I am trying to upgrade our application to CAS 6.6.15 from 5.3.16. In some scenarios, we create our own CAS service tickets, which used to work without any problems. Now, this results in INVALID_SERVICE in org.apereo.cas.validation.AuthenticationPolicyAwareServiceTicketValidationAuthorizer.
My service is defined as:
{
  "@class":  "org.apereo.cas.services.CasRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "^(http|https|imaps)://.*",
  "name": "HTTPS and IMAPS wildcard",
  "id": 1,
  "evaluationOrder": 1,
  "attributeReleasePolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.ReturnAllAttributeReleasePolicy",
    "principalAttributesRepository" : {
       "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.authentication.principal.DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository",
       "attributeRepositoryIds": ["java.util.HashSet", [ "*" ]]
    }
  },
  "serviceTicketExpirationPolicy": {
    "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceServiceTicketExpirationPolicy",
    "numberOfUses": 20,
    "timeToLive": "120"
  }
}

These log entries pinpoint where the problem occurs:
2024-05-01 13:55:10,753 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.ticket.registry.RedisTicketRegistry] - <Fetched redis key [CAS_TICKET:ST-1-********xVivEcQ-5CG22403WR] for ticket [ST-1-********xVivEcQ-5CG22403WR]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,756 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.audit.spi.principal.ThreadLocalAuditPrincipalResolver] - <Resolving principal at audit point [execution(Assertion org.apereo.cas.CentralAuthenticationService.validateServiceTicket(String,Service))]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,821 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.AbstractCasProtocolValidationSpecification] - <Is validation specification set to enforce [renew] protocol behavior? [no]. Is assertion issued from a new login? [yes]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,821 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.AbstractCasProtocolValidationSpecification] - <Number of chained authentications in the assertion [1]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,821 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.validation.AbstractCasProtocolValidationSpecification] - <Validation specification is satisfied by the produced assertion>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,821 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.audit.spi.principal.ThreadLocalAuditPrincipalResolver] - <Resolving principal at audit point [execution(boolean org.apereo.cas.validation.CasProtocolValidationSpecification.isSatisfiedBy(Assertion,HttpServletRequest))]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,822 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <No environments are assigned to service [HTTPS and IMAPS wildcard]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,822 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <No environments are assigned to service [HTTPS and IMAPS wildcard]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,822 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.validation.DelegatedAuthenticationServiceTicketValidationAuthorizer] - <Evaluating service [AbstractWebApplicationService(id=http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check, originalUrl=http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check, artifactId=ST-1-********xVivEcQ-5CG22403WR, principal=null, source=service, loggedOutAlready=false, format=XML, attributes={service=[http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check]})] for delegated authentication policy>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,824 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <No environments are assigned to service [HTTPS and IMAPS wildcard]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,824 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.services.AbstractServicesManager] - <No environments are assigned to service [HTTPS and IMAPS wildcard]>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,824 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.validation.AuthenticationPolicyAwareServiceTicketValidationAuthorizer] - <Evaluating service [AbstractWebApplicationService(id=http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check, originalUrl=http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check, artifactId=ST-1-********xVivEcQ-5CG22403WR, principal=null, source=service, loggedOutAlready=false, format=XML, attributes={service=[http://localhost:8080/core-customer/j_spring_cas_security_check]})] to ensure required authentication handlers can satisfy assertion>
2024-05-01 13:55:10,825 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.web.view.CasReloadableMessageBundle] - <Examining bundle [file:/etc/cas/config/custom_messages_en_US] for the key [INVALID_SERVICE]>

